# Clash Royale: Getting cards from shop on a lower arena

Tags: clash-royale

I'm usually at Arena 4, then I got higher to 5. I got the wizard and the zap. However I dropped back to 4.

I wanted to get more 'Zap's which is in Arena 5 but its not possible in chests as Im in a lower arena.
Is it possible to get them (Zap) in the shop on a lower arena (Arena 4).

Comment: I haven't played in a while, buy you are also able to request them from your clan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Sorry, it's not possible.

You must be in arena 5 to have the free chests, crown chests, and shop be able to contain arena 5 cards. Any chests won in arena 5 will be an arena 5 chest; which contain arena 5 cards.

NOTE: you do not have to meet the trophy requirement(1400) but it must say on the front page that you are in arena 5.